# How would I add an image instead of text?

Tags: jquery

I have four images and when it (`.panel`) slides down I can make it have text. But how would I add images, audio, or change the font color etc.

Here is a link courtesy of Karlen Kishmiryan

http://jsfiddle.net/daM6h/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $panel.html('<img src="img.png" />').slideToggle();
```

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $panel = $('.panel');
    var hello = 'Hello world, ';
    $('.wrapper').on('click', 'img', function () {
        var $img = $('<img />', {
            src: 'img.jpeg'
        })
        $panel.html($img).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/daM6h/3/)**

Comment: How would you only make it only effect one of the dropdowns?

Comment: If you want to attach to only the first element with class `panel` you can change the selector to `$('.wrapper').on('click', 'img:eq(0)', function () {`  .. A cleaner way would be is to give a class to the images and attach the event to that class instead of `img`

Answer (score 0):

use `.html('<img src="/file/filename" height="32px" width="32px"/>')`

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qkvvt/

Comment: How would I make it only effect one of the dropdowns? and make the rest not have images?